# How to pass an id of an item with a button from a list of items to a modal, then from modal to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

So I have a list of web urls, all fetched from SQL and has an id, an address etc.

I list them in a table using the following:

```
<div>
    <div class="well" margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px">
        <h2 style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:10px">Control Added Links</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Link Address
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Check Interval
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Status
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        #
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var i in links)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="http://@i.Address" target="_blank">@i.Address</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @i.Interval
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (i.Status)
                            { <text> ON </text>}
                            else
                            { <text> OFF </text>}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="~/Control/Delete/@i.Id">
                                &#10006;
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

"links" here is a list of Link models:

```
@{
    var links = (List<Link>)ViewData["LinkInfos"];
}
```

Right now, there is an X button you can click to delete a link from database, by using i.Id of the item 'i'. What I want to do is, ask for a confirmation with a modal, instead of directly deleting.

I delete the link with a function inside controller using the follownig:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
{
    UserLinks links = new UserLinks();
    links.delete(Id, User.Identity.Name);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I changed this code, managed to pass the data from button to modal:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="@i.Id" data-request-url="@Url.Action("Delete", "Control")" title="Delete link" class="delete-Link btn btn-danger" href="#deleteLink">
    &#10006;
</a>

<div id="deleteLink" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Test</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                This will delete all records related to this link. Are you sure?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deleteConfirm()">Yes</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var myLinkId
    var url
    $(document).on("click", ".delete-Link", function () {
        myLinkId = $(this).data('id');
        url = $(this).data('request-url');
        $(".modal-body #linkId").val(myLinkId);
        // As pointed out in comments,
        // it is superfluous to have to manually call the modal.
        // $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
    });
    function deleteConfirm()
    {
        debugger;
        $.post(url), { Id: myLinkId };
    }
</script>
```

But problem right now is passing this data from modal to controller. I wrote the "deleteConfirm" function but it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't go to ~/Control/Delete.

First part of my question is actually solved, I can pass id from button to modal, but I am not sure if it is properly solved so I am asking for that too, I currently pass the id using JavaScript but wonder if I can directly pass from button to modal itself.

I managed to fix my issue and properly delete by creating a modal for each item... which I assume is the sloppy way and can be a problem when I have like, let's say 100 links.

**One solution I have in mind but don't know how to implement:**

Have a "globalId" parameter inside view, when a button is clicked, i.Id is assigned to globalId, then open the modal, which has globalId as a parameter inside. Just like with , use  inside modal, which changes by deletion button you click. But problem is, don't know how to create this global parameter and assign i.Id to it with click of a button.

**A way I think I can implement my possible solution:**

I want to have a variable in a view, let's say int globalId.

Let's say I press the delete button for id = 10, what I want to happen is simply have "global = id" so I want to assign 10 to number. If id of button is 12, I want "global = id" to happen again, this time to assign 12 to number.

So this way, modal will just use globalId, so I can make it have:

```
<a href="~/Control/Delete/@globalId">Yes</a>
```

This way, there will only be one modal, every button will open the same modal and modal will use the same variable. Just value for globalId assigned to this modal will change with click of a button.

Question is, how can I create this local variable and how can I simply assign a new value to this local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in your view which make this possible to work. I have added one hidden field in model and store the id on show event of the model. And on confirm id is get from this hidden field to construct the post url.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="@id" data-request-url="@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")" title="Delete link" class="delete-Link btn btn-danger" href="#deleteLink">
    &#10006;
</a>

<div id="deleteLink" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <input type="hidden" id="linkId" />
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Test</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                This will delete all records related to this link. Are you sure?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deleteConfirm()">Yes</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#deleteLink').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#linkId").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('id'));
    });

    function deleteConfirm()
    {
        var url = "@Url.Action("Delete", "Control")/" + $("#linkId").val();
        $.post(url).success(function () {
            location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Control")";
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. But there is a problem I don't understand, normally when deleting is complete or @Url.Action("Delete", "Control") is done, it should refresh the page and show the new table of links but it doesn't refresh?

Comment: Also it doesn't close the modal when clicked yes. Which isn't a problem since it will refresh the page but refreshing AFTER closing the modal would probably look better. What do you think causes this? EDIT: Okay I added data-dismiss="modal" which fixed modal not closing. But it still doesn't refresh page.

Comment: Still doesn't refresh

Comment: It says "TypeError: $.post(...).success is not a function"

Comment: But it is working fine my side. Can you paste `$.post` block?

Comment: $.post(url).success(function () {
            location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Control")"; as you typed

Comment: Then replace success with done like $.post(url).done(..).